# How can I add a do while loop to my code?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

How can I add a do while loop so when the FileNotFoundException class is encountered, my user is informed that the file does not exist and provides my user the opportunity to enter another file name? This is what I have so far. Thanks

```
 do
{
      // Get a file name from the user.
      fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " +
                                "the name of a file:");

      // Attempt to open the file.
      try
      {
         file = new File(fileName);
         inputFile = new Scanner(file);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                          "The file was found.");
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e)
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                               "File not found.");
      }

///// while(flag+f)

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done.");
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... Add a flag 'ok' and do what you do until it gets true. Than stop the loop.

```
boolean ok = false;
 do
{
  // Get a file name from the user.
  fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " +
                            "the name of a file:");

  // Attempt to open the file.
  try
  {
     file = new File(fileName);
     inputFile = new Scanner(file);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                      "The file was found.");
 ok = true;
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                           "File not found.");
  }

 while(ok == false);}

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done.");
  System.exit(0);
}
```